# how to get timestamp from oracle DB using jdbc

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

how to get timestamp from oracle DB using JDBC? on sql i can use 
select sysdate from dual.

i was trying something like

```
ResultSet rs = <>.createPreparedStatement("select sysdate from dual");
rs.executeQuery();

while(rs.next())
  rs.get<What to write here?>
```

Comment: Did you check ResultSet javadoc? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getTimestamp(int)

Comment: did you check this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21162753/jdbc-resultset-i-need-a-getdatetime-but-there-is-only-getdate-and-gettimestamp

Answer (score 2):

`rs.get(1)` will solve the problem. otherwise give the alias name to the column and use that.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT SYSTIMESTAMP FROM DUAL;
```

SYSTIMESTAMP returns the system date, including fractional seconds and time zone, of the system on which the database resides. The return type is TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE.

Comment: What it does? try to explain.

Answer (score -1):

If the value of `sysdate` is an `int` you can use this:

```
  while(rs.next()){
   int sysdate= rs.getInt("sysdate");
```

But if the value of `sysdate` is a `String` you can use this:

```
   while(rs.next()){
   String sysdate= rs.getString("sysdate");
```

For more info go to [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/retrieving.html)