# Oracle date has not time from java

Tags: java, oracle, date, oracle-sqldeveloper

My application is using an Oracle database and one of the table contains a date column. When doing my queries inside *SQLDeveloper* I need to add the following line to get the date + hours

```
alter session set nls_date_format = 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS';
```

If I do not use this, I only see the date like `25/11/2016`

---

When I am doing my queries from my JAVA code I don't have the above line thus every date is returned in the format `DD/MM/YY`

**JAVA**

```
String query = "SELECT date from SCHEMA.table";
ResultSet rs = null;
try {
    connection = ConnectionFactory.getConnection(Database.ORACLE);
    preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(query);

    rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
    while (rs.next()) {
        java.sql.Date dateDB = rs.getDate("date");
    }
catch(SQLException e){
    //error
}
```

How can I get the date with the hours ? Should I add `alter session ...` to each query ?

Comment: How do you retrieve the data from the database? And how do you _display_ it from inside your code? **[edit]** your question and add the Java code that retrieves and displays the date.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Question updated

Comment: Similar issue is addressed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21162753/jdbc-resultset-i-need-a-getdatetime-but-there-is-only-getdate-and-gettimestamp)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Description part of `java.sql.Date`:

> To conform with the definition of SQL DATE, the millisecond values wrapped 
>   by a java.sql.Date instance must be 'normalized' by setting the hours, 
>   minutes, seconds, and milliseconds to zero

Probably the `java.sql.Timestamp` is the correct type which includes the time components:

```
    ...
    java.sql.Timestamp dateDB = rs.getTimestamp("date");
    ...
```

Comment: Which means, you need to use `ResultSet.getTimestamp()` not `getDate()`