# Retrieve Date information from table with Timestamp and convert into 24hr format string

Tags: java, datetime, sybase, datetime-format

I am having a field like this in my database table `Jan  1 1900 10:22PM` . I am getting it out like this `result.setEndingDate(rs.getDate("end_tm"));` . when i do an sysout the output is displayed in the console  as `1900-01-01` . What can i do to get Time stamp and also to conver it into 24 hour format .My output String String should be somehting like this `22:10` . how can i proceed to achieve this

Comment: take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21162753/jdbc-resultset-i-need-a-getdatetime-but-there-is-only-getdate-and-gettimestamp

Comment: Was just going through that link . Thanks

Comment: i am getting output like this `1900-01-01 22:22:00.0` how can i get   `22:22` alone ?

Comment: take a look at SimpleDateFormat :)

Comment: ```---Thanks mate !!---```